# document.GetElementsByName not working when echoed in PHP class

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working on an application that renders a collage of images (album covers). However, whenever I run this code, the update function doesn't send an alert, so I'm assuming it cannot find any elements with the name I assigned with the onClick function. Why is that? The render function works fine and assigns the name properly. The classes are in PHP, but the user input (click events, etc.) is handled in Javascript.

Here is the render function which is located in the Album class:

```
public function render()
{
        echo
        "<script>function setName(id){document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('name','selected');}</script>" .
        "<input type='image' onClick='setName(this.id)' id='$this->id' src='" . $this->url . "'/>";
}
```

Here is the update function which is located in the Chart class (manages Album objects):

```
public function update($url)
{
        echo
        "<script type='text/javascript'>" .
        "var clicked = document.getElementsByName('selected');" .
        "alert(clicked[0].id);" .
        "document.getElementById(clicked[0].id).src='" . $url . "';" .
        "clicked[0].setAttribute('name','');" .
        "</script>";
}
```

Comment: no, dont echo in a function. please return string instead and echo that string..

Comment: what do you mean? Do I put the Javascript code in a string and then echo that?

Comment: @BagusTesa The render function works fine as it is so I don't think that's the problem

Comment: `document.getElementsByName('selected');"` or `document.getElementsByName('select');"`

Comment: @TanDuong 'selected' is the name of the element I'm trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with event `DOMContentLoaded` to make sure DOM element is ready. You need to wrap all your getElement into this function

```
public function update($url)
{
        echo
        "<script type='text/javascript'>" .
        "document.addEventListener(\"DOMContentLoaded\", function(event) { ".
        "var clicked = document.getElementsByName('selected');" .
        "alert(clicked[0].id);" .
        "document.getElementById(clicked[0].id).src='" . $url . "';" .
        "clicked[0].setAttribute('name','');" .
        "});"
        "</script>";
}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was that no element was named 'selected' after the form submission. In order to solve this, I simply added a hidden input named 'selected' and assigned the last clicked button's id to its value.

```
<script>
    function setName(id)
    {
        var button = document.getElementsByName('selected');
        button[0].value = id;
    }
</script>

<form name='search' action="" method="post">
<input name="query" type="text" size="100"></input>
<input name='selected' type='hidden'></input>
<input class="submit" type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

the update function works properly now on my machine.